# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object One to One relation

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

Users Schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) 
    {
        $table->create();

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('real_name');
        $table->string('password');

        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Dni Schema

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('dnis', function($table){
            $table->create();

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('numero',15);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have These models

```
User:

    <?php
    class User extends Eloquent
    {
      public function setPassword($string) 
      {
        $this->setAttribute('password', Hash::make($string));
      }
      public function dni()
      {
        return $this->hasOne('Dni', 'user_id');
      }
    }
```

Dni

```
<?php
class Dni extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And when i try to

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return View::make('users.index') -> with('users', $users);
    }
```

I use a foreach in my view and cant get `{{ $user->dni->numero }}` to work
I guess i'm missing something in `getIndex()` but can't figure out what.

I used `var_dump($users)` and `var_dump($user)` in the foreach and i seems that no dni date is being sent on $users

Comment: Could you share your template code?

Comment: `code<h1>Users</h1>
@if($users)
<ul>
  @foreach($users as $user)
 <li>{{ $user->real_name }} - {{ $user->email }} - {{ $user->dni->numero }}
     {{ HTML::link('UserController/delete/'.$user->id, 'Borrar') }} - 
     {{ HTML::link('UserController/update/'.$user->id, 'Actualizar un Usuario') }}
 </li>
  @endforeach`

Comment: What does the schema for the `users` and `dni` tables look like?

Comment: Added Schemas to post.

Comment: Did you already try to `$users->load('dni')` and then try to `var_dump` the $users after that?

Comment: Yes and i got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dni()`

Comment: If you're able would you be willing to add the related files to github? It's probably a small error somewhere.

Comment: Here is the Github rep [https://github.com/Mercality/videotutorialescom]

Comment: You should implement `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` interfaces and `getAuthIdentifier`, `RemindableInterface` and `getReminderEmail` methods to make your user model work peoperly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you're not eager loading this. Each time you iterate over $users you're making a database query to get the Dni model for each individual user. Pass the variable to your view as such:

```
$users = User::with('dni')->get();
```

The problem you're having could be that you don't have a Dni object for each individual user in which case you could grab the users with:

```
$users = User::has('Dni')->with('dni')->get();
```

---

**Solution:**
It looks like Laravel doesn't like your duplicate class name in User1.php and is calling that user model instead of your alternative one. You can either delete User1.php and run `composer dump-autoload` or change the name of the class inside of User1.php and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: The two methods return `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Dni()` i am starting to think there is a problem with my model because the password hasher i have in the User model does nothing, i go to the DB and it shows the non hashed password when i add a new user. What could be the problem then? the models?

Comment: @Mercality give me a moment to install the application and see if I can't see what you're problem is.

Comment: It's in the solution above.

Comment: Where did you find `User1.php` and it looks like `OP` is making some mistakes because he should not get `all to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Dni()` instead each model should be an instance of `User` model.

Comment: Oh my god... Can't belive it was such a dumb thing hehe. Works as expected. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am new to Laravel and when i was doing the tutorial y just renamed the default `User.php` to `User1.php` i had no idea it was going to load. Removing it solved the problem. But it still can't hash the passwords i tried `setPassword` and `set_password`. Also `set_attribute` and `setAttribute`

Comment: @SheikhHeera He posted the entirety of the code in Github in his comments on the original question. It is an instance of the User model, but the wrong one. He SHOULD be getting the exact error he's getting, thanks for playing.

Comment: @Mercality just use $user->password = Hash::make($password); You will want to be using the original user model that laravel provided you however, not the one you're using currently.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

```
 @if($student>subjects)
 {{  $student>subjects->name }}
 @endif
```